# Documentclass for Homework Problems

Tags: document-classes, ctan

Are there any good documentclasses on CTAN (or built in to some distributions) that are designed for turning in homework problem sets?  I've managed to find [one](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/assignment), but it's a bit awkward. Are there any others?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used the [exam](http://ctan.org/pkg/exam) class to make quizzes and exams. How different would homework sets be?

Comment: I want to turn in a problem set, not create one.  I've edited the question to clarify.

Comment: I'm not sure how different the requirements are. I've used exam to make the things I hand out, and to make the grading keys, which would resemble the submitted homework. Being entirely unsure how the assignment class you found is awkward, I don't know whether the exam class is an improvement or not.

Comment: @Dan, I believe `exam` would provide the same structure (question-answer pairs).

Comment: @Mike: Uh..if the problems are from a book and I want to specify the problem number, how can I do it with the `exam` package? Thank you!

Comment: The only way I can see to do that is to explicitly use `\setcounter{question}{value}` before each `\question`. `value` should be one less than the problem number you want, since the `\question` command will automatically increment the number. For anything else, just post a new question, to avoid this page becoming cluttered.