# Class file for Homework/Assignments

Tags: templates

I was wondering if there is a good general purpose homework class file/template out there. I want to use it for classes. Generally, math-centered courses. I would like if there was syntax highlighting for programming (Python, Ruby, C, Java, etc.).

Comment: You might also want to look into the `answers` package, it is very nice =)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For the class file itself: I actually made my own class file (adapted from the `report` class file) to format my homework the way I wanted. It is here, if you're interested in trying it or fiddling with it:

https://gist.github.com/1278588

You supply it with `\author` and `\title` in the preamble, and it automatically uses today's date.

This file is used by inserting `\documentclass{jhwhw}` at the beginning of a document.

The standard formatting for a problem looks like this:

```
\problem{NAME OF PROBLEM}
  <<statements of problem>>
\solution
  <<solution>>
```

It creates a new page for every problem. Also, if a problem has multiple "parts" the formatting might look like this

```
\problem{NAME OF PROBLEM}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item <<Part (a) problem statement>>
    \item <<Part (b) problem statement>>
  \end{enumerate}
\solution
  \part
    <<Solution to part (a)>>
  \part
    <<Solution to part (b)>>
```

The `enumerate` will use letters (a), (b), etc. And `\part` will use (a), then (b), etc.

An example page (from a real homework assignment) looks like this [image: picture]

If you want to try it out, download it, put it in your `texmf` folder and run `texconfig rehash` (if you're on a UNIX based system).

There are definitely things in this class file that are automated that people would want more control over, so I suggest fiddling around to find what works best for you.

For syntax highlighting: [Werner's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31183/class-file-for-homework-assignments/31184#31184) mentioning the `listings` package for syntax highlighting and code is great. (*That* style file could be used with **this** class file.)

Comment: Hey man is there a way to prevent each problem from starting on a new page?

Comment: Yeah, in the `\newcommand*{\anyproblem}[1]{\newpage\subsection*{#1}}` line of the style file (as of this writing: L60), remove the `\newpage`. That should prevent it from starting each problem on a new page.

Answer (score 9):

In my opinion the (standard) `article` document class would work for that. The reason for not suggesting something like `book` or `report` is that they are meant for much larger texts (since they include chapters and parts). Additional syntax-highlight can be obtained by means of the [`listings` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) - you specify the language (and possibly other formatting) and put the code in a `lstlisting` environment and that's that. See the [`listings` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) for more information on this (p 12 presents a list of supported languages, although you can define your own).

For mathematical typesetting, I would suggest using the [`amsmath` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) as well. It provides the powerful `align` environment for typesetting equations (numbered; otherwise, for unnumbered equations using `align*`) with alignment properties. It also improves on other standard mathematical components used in LaTeX.

Here's an outline of what I'm talking about:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
% ... other packages that you may want to use
\begin{document}
% Sectional headings...
% Paragraph text...
% Enumerate/itemize environments...
% Listings (or programming code segments)...
% Tables...
% Figures...
% Mathematics (align, align*, \[ \], ...)
\end{document}
```

If, in general, your expertise in LaTeX needs a solid foundation, consider reading through the [Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2ε](http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf).

Comment: Also consider the [exam](http://ctan.org/pkg/exam) class ([related question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28079/documentclass-for-homework-problems/28080#28080)) for a question/answer structure.

Answer (score 5):

You can make a [topic search at CTAN](http://ctan.org/topic/) and under exams you will find a complete list of packages related with [exercises](http://ctan.org/topic/exercise) or [exams](http://ctan.org/topic/exam). I think most of them are compatible with `listings` and `minted` to typeset code.

Comment: The links have since rotted. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Broken link....

Comment: @JPCF I've revised links.