# How to keep section numbering and title in same line?

Tags: sectioning, formatting, line-breaking

I am working to modify [this Latex template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31183/class-file-for-homework-assignments) from stackexchange to use for my homework. Namely, the template currently splits the title of a subsection from its numbering, like so:

[image]

And, as mentioned in the image, I would like it to act more like:

> Part (a) I would prefer this formatting

The only file that seems to be involved in setting up the section headers is bachw.cls. Which defines them in this way:

```
% Set up counters for problems and subsections

\newcounter{ProblemNum}
\newcounter{SubProblemNum}[ProblemNum]

\renewcommand{\theProblemNum}{\arabic{ProblemNum}}
\renewcommand{\theSubProblemNum}{\alph{SubProblemNum}}

\newcommand*{\anyproblem}[1]{\newpage\subsection*{#1}}
\newcommand*{\problem}[1]{\stepcounter{ProblemNum} %
  \anyproblem{Problem \theProblemNum. \; #1}}
\newcommand*{\soln}[1]{\subsubsection*{#1}}
\newcommand*{\solution}{\soln{Solution}}
\newcommand*{\subproblem}{\stepcounter{SubProblemNum} %
  \soln{Part (\theSubProblemNum)}}
```

The code I used to generate the image above was:

```
\documentclass{bachw}
\begin{document}

\problem{This is in-line and good}
\subproblem{I would like this to be in line with the `Part (a)'}

\end{document}
```

I've tried modifying the \subproblem and \problem lines in bachw.cls a little, taking out the '[1]' or adding it, taking out the %s and seeing what that changes but I am very out of my element. Where can I tell \subproblem to hold the linebreak?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You can try to use the `titlesec` package, and redefine `\subsubsection`  as having the `runin` style.

Comment: OTOH, if you don't need a table of contents or headings, you could just use enumerate.

Comment: Thanks @Bernard! I have added `titlesec` to the list of required packages but I am not sure what you mean by `redefine \subsubsection has having the runin style`. I tried adding [runin] to the end of  `\newcommand*{\subproblem}{\stepcounter{SubProblemNum} %
  \soln{Part (\theSubProblemNum)}}` but that causes problems during compilation and I've tried adding it to `\newcommand*{\soln}[1]{\subsubsection*{#1}[runin]}` and `\newcommand*{\soln}[1]{\subsubsection*{#1}}[runin]` but no luck.

Comment: You have to use the advanced interface: `\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]{…}` and enter formatting the parameters of your document class (font size, font shape, font weight, spacing between label and title, &c.)

Comment: You will probably want to consult the documentation for `titlesec` at https://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec?lang=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Bernard and @Teepeemm for the help. I have solved it by adding:

```
\RequirePackage{titlesec}
%=====================================================================
% Title Modifications
%=====================================================================
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]{\bfseries}{}{}{}[]
```

To line 35 of bachw.cls.